# Is it allowed to replace 'keine' with 'nicht'?

Tags: negation

The sentence `I did not eat pizza` is translated to `Ich habe keine Pizza gegessen` (correct me if I am wrong).
Is it allowed to say `Ich habe nicht Pizza gegessen`?
If yes, does it have the same meaning?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to German StackExchange. I’m correcting your sentence since it is wrong ;) It shouldn’t be »Ich habe **keinen** Pizza gegessen« but »Ich habe **keine** Pizza gegessen«.

Comment: This might also help: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7677/kein-klavier-or-nicht-klavier-spielen

Comment: @Philipp: Mit Deiner Reputation müsstest Du solche Kleinigkeiten, die den Sinn der Frage nicht entstellen, sondern im Sinne des Fragers sind, doch selbst durch ein Edit heilen können. Die wichtigste Faustregel ist damit schon benannt. Details finden sich wohl bei "Tour" bzw. "Help Center" unter dem Fragezeichen.

Comment: @userunknown Das hätte ich getan, wenn der Zusatz in Klammern nicht gewesen wäre. So wirkte es wie ein »Wie muss es richtig heißen?«, und darauf bin ich eingegangen.

Comment: Für mich wirkt es wie "korrigiert mich, wenn ich falsch liege" und kann die Vorwegnahme der dann folgenden Frage bedeuten (is it allowed to say ...) oder eine Bitte um Korrektur sonstiger Fehler. Unabhängig davon, ob solch eine Bitte geäußert wird, sollte man solche Korrekturen vornehmen, so dass sich zukünftige Leser auf die eigentliche Fragen konzentrieren und nicht lange und breit über Fragen gestritten wird, die zu stellen nicht beabsichtigt war.